# React Native dynamically adding Animation via Map

Tags: react-native

I am having a really hard time figuring out why I am unable to add a simple animation to a card deck. I want to animate a single card every time a button is pressed. I am able to achieve this on a single card, but after the second render the animations no longer applies. I am using setState to keep track of the button presses and a bit of logic to apply the Animated.View on the card that is next on the list. So in my mind, when the app first runs all cards in the deck are displayed, user presses the button first card is  removed and so on and so fourth.

```
export default class Cards extends React.Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    this.animatedValue = new Animated.ValueXY(0, 0);
  }
  state = { index: 0 };

  renderCards = () => {
    console.log("App started");
    const { data } = this.props;
    return data.map((cards, idx) => {
      if (idx < this.state.index) {
        return null;
      }

      if (idx === this.state.index) {
        console.log("animated being added to " + idx);
        console.log(` the state is  ${this.state.index} in renderCards `);
        return (
          <View>
            <Animated.View style={[this.animatedValue.getLayout()]}>
              <Card>
                <Text>Animated Value</Text>
              </Card>
            </Animated.View>
          </View>
        );
      }

      return (
        <View>
          <Card>
            <Text>No Animation</Text>
          </Card>
        </View>
      );
    });
  };
  nextCard = () => {
    Animated.spring(this.animatedValue, {
      toValue: { x: 500, y: 0 }
    }).start();
    this.setState({ index: this.state.index + 1 });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.cardContainer}>
        {this.renderCards()}
        <Button
          large
          icon={{ name: "envira", type: "font-awesome" }}
          title="Press me"
          style={styles.button}
          onPress={() => this.nextCard()}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

The second render two cards disappear but I do not see why this is happening.

I am unsure on what I am doing wrong.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that the Animated Value (this.animatedValue) isn't reset.

The rendering view of the 'active card' (where idx === this.state.index) is fixed to the value of this.animatedValue. You'll want to reset this value back to 0,0 after the animation. Right now, it stays at x: 500, y:0 and is rendering the next card off-screen (disappearing).

I would update your nextCard function to do this in the animation callback:

```
nextCard = () => {
  Animated.spring(this.animatedValue, {
    toValue: { x: 500, y: 0 },
  }).start(() => {
    this.animatedValue = new Animated.ValueXY(0, 0);
    this.setState({ index: this.state.index + 1 });
  });
};
```

Note that the ordering of updating the animatedValue and setting the state matters as the state triggers a re-render.

Comment: Hey Greg, thank you for taking the time. I did not realize that I had to reset the values back. That was extremely helpful and I really appreciate the help.